# Email sending code working on localhost but not on server

Tags: c#, email, visual-studio-2015, smtp, smtpclient

I have written an email sending code using c#. I used GoDaddy's server for my website. It is working on localhost (VS 2013), But when deployed the same code on the server it gives the following error:

---

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   [2607:f8b0:400e:c05::6c]:25

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt fail because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or establish connection fail because connected host has failed to respond [2607:f8b0:400e:c05::6c]:25

Stack Trace:

> [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed t
>   SMS.Portal.SendSMS.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   d:\Paul\ProximityMarketer\smsproximitysource\source\Portal\SendSMS.aspx.cs:30
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9633514
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +103
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web...IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1724

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET version:4.0.30319.34280

---

Code is given below:

```
SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
smtpclient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtpclient.Port = 25;
smtpclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxx@gmail.com", "Password");
smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
MailMessage objmsg = new MailMessage();
objmsg.From = new MailAddress("xxxxx@gmail.com");
objmsg.To.Add(email);
objmsg.Subject = "testing";
objmsg.Body = myString.ToString();
objmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
smtpclient.Send(objmsg);
```

Comment: `smtpclient.Port = 25;` Are you sure you can use port 25 on public hosting server?

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking this on the hosted server perhaps?

Comment: gmail will not use port 25 which is unsecure email.  You need to use TLS which is port number 587.  See wbpage : https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491

Comment: Working with Port 80. Thanks @vendettamit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Someone recommended me the Article. https://pk.godaddy.com/help/see-your-smtp-relays-3552. And I used the following code:

```
SmtpClient ss = new SmtpClient();
ss.Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
ss.Port = 80;
ss.Timeout = 10000;
ss.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
ss.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
ss.EnableSsl = false;
ss.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@yourdomain.com", "password");

MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage("abc@yourdomain.com", email, "subject here", "my body");
mailMsg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
ss.Send(mailMsg);
```

***Note: It was not working with port 25.***