# Email working in Test case but not in IIS (localdev or server)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mailmessage

I have an issue where emails are sent out correctly when executed in unit testing in Visual Studio.

However, the exact same piece of code and configuration does not work on IIS.
Instead I receive a IO Exception error:

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format`

```
public void SendEmail(List<string> toAddress, string fromAddress, string subject, string htmlBody)
        {
            var mail = new MailMessage();

            mail.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);

            toAddress.ForEach(x=>mail.To.Add(x));
            var client = new SmtpClient();

            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = htmlBody;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            client.Send(mail);
}

<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="mail@domain.com.au">
        <network host="mail.blah.com.au" port="26" userName="username" password="password" enableSsl="false" 
                  defaultCredentials="false"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Anyone had similar experience?

Comment: Welcome, would you be able to provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to examine?

Comment: I think you can get your answer from below link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945560/email-sending-code-working-on-localhost-but-not-on-server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755637/the-handshake-failed-due-to-an-unexpected-packet-format-with-smtpclient Found the answer.
I had to set the Protocol.